# How to get data from handler

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, handler, message

In my android project I have java class that implements IUSBDeviceObserver interface.

```
public class LensPickerActivity extends CarActivity 
    implements LensPickerSelectionHandler,IUSBDeviceObserver{

    private Context mContext;
    private PackageManager mPackageManager;
    private PagedListView mPagedListView;
    MediaReceiver mediaReceiver;    
    private String mDeviceName = "";
    private static final int UPDATE_USB_NAME = 1

    public LensPickerActivity(Proxy proxy, Context context, Car car) {
        super(proxy, context, car);     

        mContext = context;
        mPackageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        mSharedPrefs = LensPickerUtils.getFacetSharedPrefs(mContext);


    }

    // override function from IUSBDeviceObserver
    @Override
    public void onUSBDeviceChanged(String device) {

        mDeviceName = device;        
        Log.d(TAG,"device name ++++"+" "+mDeviceName);
        getAttachedDeviceName(mDeviceName);

    }
}
```

In onUSBDeviceChanged() function I am getting String value but How pass that string to LensPickerActivity context ?. I mean main thread. I am using Handler mechanisam but it is not working for me. below is Hanlder class

```
private void getAttachedDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        Message message = mHandlerPhone.obtainMessage(UPDATE_USB_NAME);
        if (deviceName == null) return;
        message.obj = deviceName;
        Log.d(TAG, "aTTCHEDdEVICE Name :: " + deviceName);
        mHandlerPhone.sendMessage(message);
    }

    Handler mHandlerPhone = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case UPDATE_USB_NAME:
                    String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");
                    Log.d(TAG, "aTTCHEDdEVICE Name handler :: " + aResponse);
                   break;
                default:

            }
        }
    };
```

In mHandlerPhone  I am getting String is null. How get String value in Main thread.

Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Your `Handler` code appears to be outside a method body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg.obj` contains your `String`, so try to use:

```
Handler mHandlerPhone = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case UPDATE_USB_NAME:
                    String aResponse = (String) msg.obj;
                    Log.d(TAG, "aTTCHEDdEVICE Name handler :: " + aResponse);
                   break;
                default:

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more Qn. How to get data from Handler and update to OnCreate method